# C# Winforms: Set text in ComboBox based on selected Item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm new to `c#` and I'm now learning how to trigger events based on some form actions.

This is part of view:

```
private void comboGoodsName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    controller.selectName(comboGoodsName.Text);
}

public void nameChanged(object sender, MeasurementEventArgs e)
{
    comboGoodsName.TextChanged -= comboGoodsName_TextChanged;
    comboGoodsName.Text = e.value;
    comboGoodsName.TextChanged += comboGoodsName_TextChanged;
}
```

And this is part of controller:

```
public void selectName(string name)
{          
    model.Name = name.Split('|')[0].Trim();

    if (name.Contains(" | "))
    {
        string code = name.Split('|')[1].Trim();
        model.NameCode = code;
    }
}
```

The scenario is as follows:
I want to have a `ComboBox` with some items in it (doesn't matter what's the source). Items are combination of name and code in following format: `NAME | CODE`. When I enter some text in `ComboBox` (type it in), `comboGoodsName_TextChanged` is triggered, which in turn calls `selectName` which sets model's property, which in turn raises an event which is observed by `nameChanged`. This works fine, as expected (puts `NAME` in `ComboBox` and `CODE` to `TextBox` - not shown as not relevant). Problem shows up when I select item from `ComboBox` drop-down list. When I select item, instead of showing `NAME` in `ComboBox`, I see `NAME | CODE`.

Edit: In the model, property is set correctly, which I confirmed by printing its value. So, issue is related only to displaying proper value in `ComboBox`.

Comment: Trying to understand your requirement.  Do you ever want the user to see CODE in the combobox?  If not why not use the ComboBox  property *DisplayMember* for **NAME** and *ValueMember* for **CODE**?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be displayed, so user can distinguish between different items. And, when user selects an item, one piece of information goes to combobox and another to textbox.

Comment: What triggers **nameChanged()**?

Comment: It is triggered in the model when the name property is set (using custom `EventHandler`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void comboGoodsName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if combobox has selected item then continue
    if (comboGoodsName.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // split the selecteditem text on the pipe into a string array then pull the first element in the array i.e. NAME
        string nameOnly = comboGoodsName.GetItemText(this.comboGoodsName.SelectedItem).Split('|')[0];

        // handing off the reset of the combobox selected value to a delegate method - using methodinvoker on the forms main thread is an efficient to do this
        // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.comboGoodsName.Text = nameOnly; });
    }      
}
```

Comment: Since I'm newbie, can You explain what does this do? BTW, it is working as expected now.